# Microsoft Access VBA for opening different Form based conditional string in column of table

Tags: vba, ms-access

obligatory mention that I have little understanding of VBA:

I have a table with data that needs to be displayed through one of two different Forms based on the value of a column within the table, after a command is run/button clicked.

The data is housed in the same table, but needs separate forms to display differently based on the value of the column.
Reference:

**Table**  master_schools_tbl

**column**  school

**Form 1** East_Town_High_frm

**Form 2**  West_Town_High_frm

Apologies for lack of basic syntax knowledge, and below was my final attempt and I understand its weird to use a condition to then set that same condition.

example code I cant get to work-

```
Dim stDocName as string
Dim stLinkCriteria as string


If [school] = "East" Then 
stDocName="East_Town_High_frm" 
stLinkCriteria="[School]='East'"
ElseIF [school] = "West" Then 
stDocName="West_Town_High_frm" 
stLinkCriteria="[School]='West'"
EndIf

DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName,,,stLinkCriteria
```

Comment: `stDocName="East_Town_High_frm"`

Comment: I edited the code example to quote the form names

Comment: `EndIf` = `End If`  you have no option for if the school isn't east or west either, no `else`

Answer (score 0):

Could shorten code to:

```
If Not IsNull([school]) Then 
DoCmd.OpenForm [school] & "_Town_High_frm", , , "[School]='" & [School] & "'"
End If
```

Setting the filter in VBA won't prevent user changing filter on form with ribbon or shortcut menu unless you deactivate those tools. Instead of filter criteria in VBA, each form could have an SQL in RecordSource property that has static filter.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [School]="West";
```

If these forms are identical in structure, why not just have one form to maintain? Use VBA to set label captions or expressions in textboxes for dynamic descriptions on form. Use VBA to set the form RecordSource so the filter is static as described above.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. The forms are not identical in structure, but the underlying table (master_schools_tbl) I was able to retrofit to hold the data that will populate both forms. IRL, the forms are actually not named as similar as they are in my example. If I were to change the RecordSource property in the filter, with two different form names, how would the DoCmd.OpenForm syntax change

Comment: Could either go back to the `If Then` and setting a variable you originally used or use IIf(): `DoCmd.OpenForm IIf([school] = "West", "form1", "form2")` or rename the forms.

Comment: thanks again, now using the DoCmd.OpenForm IIf([school] = "West", "form1", "form2") method, I receive the error:  .. can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression, which is an error that has plagued this whole process.

Comment: Never mentioned this issue in your narrative. You said "code I cant get to work" but not what exactly happens - error message, wrong result, nothing. If that is a VBA error message, what line triggers it? Is it OpenForm? Is [school] a field/control on form? Try `Me.School`.

Comment: Agreed, didn't offer enough details - the  command I am trying to update is launched by clicking a button on a separate form that then would previously just pull up the East_Town_High_frm form. Now that there is a new form, West_Town_High_frm, that button needs to launch either of the forms based on the criteria I had outlined above.  The error i have received is the "can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression, and I understand that it seems not to be able to understand where I am referencing [school] from.  The error message is on 1st line of code - Private Sub Command Click

Comment: If debugger is highlighting line `Private Sub Command_Click`, then the procedure is not even running. Have you debug/compiled? We don't know your db structure nor form designs so can't really analyze this error. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis. I hope button is not named just Command.